# Necessity of coprimeness in Carmichael numbers

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

From http://oeis.org/wiki/Carmichael_numbers, Carmichael numbers are (1) "composite numbers $n$ which divide  $b^n  −  b$  for every integer  $b$ .   OR equivalently (2) Carmichael numbers have the property that  $b^{n  − 1}  ≡   1  \pmod n$  for all bases  $b$  coprime to  $n$."

So essentially my question is: why  does the second definition requires $b$ to be coprime to $n$ and the first doesn't?

I tried to go from $b^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod n$ (with $b$ coprime) to $b^n \equiv b \pmod n$ for ANY $b$ 
but I hit a lot of dead ends.

Comment: It's simple, really.  Given $b^n\equiv b$ you get $b^{n-1}\equiv 1$ through dividing by $b$.  But, that is allowed only if $b$ has a multiplicative inverse $\bmod n$ so the division becomes a multiplication, and this requires $b, n$ to be relatively prime.

Comment: Compare to [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), where the same distinction arises.

Comment: @Oscar Of course it's simple if you choose the trivial direction of the equivalence. The other direction is not so simple, and is what the OP actually asks about.

Comment: @Matías Santurio: See corollary $4$ in this article:$\;$https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ugradnumthy/carmichaelkorselt.pdf

Comment: That's it thank you very much @quasi